# MySQL, procedure how to find a ships firepower

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a procedure to find the firepower of a class of ships. (The firepower is the number of guns * the displacement cubed)

Relation:

```
Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)
```

What I have tried so far...

```
CREATE PRODCEDURE firePower(in className VARCHAR(50), out p int)
-> begin
-> set p = (SELECT numGuns FROM classes WHERE class = className) * (SELECT displacement
FROM classes WHERE class = className)* (SELECT displacement FROM classes WHERE class
className)
-> * (SELECT displacement FROM classes WHERE class = className)
-> )
-> end;
-> //
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRODCEDURE
firePower(in className VARCHAR(50), out p int)
begin
set p = (SELECT ' at line 1
```

I know this is a terrible query. I am not looking for performance just trying to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but doesn't work in a comment:

why are you doing all those subselects? You're fetching different fields from the same table with the same where clause, you could be simply doing:

```
SELECT numGuns * displacement * displacement * displacement
FROM classes
WHERE class = className
```

Answer (score 1):

The first issue that sticks out to me is that you mispelled "PROCEDURE":

```
CREATE PRODCEDURE ...
```

should be

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
```

Comment: hehehe. Yes this could also be the problem.